# binding a minor mode's function to already defined key in global-map

Tags: key-bindings, use-package

```
(use-package
  anaconda-mode
  :defer t
  :config
  (progn
    (unbind-key "M-." anaconda-mode-map)
    (unbind-key "C-_" global-map))
  :bind ((:map anaconda-mode-map
               ("C-_" . anaconda-mode-find-definitions))))
```

but when I do `C-_`, it is undefined. `anaconda-mode-map` doesn't have `C-_`.

Comment: I do not use `use-package` nor `anaconda-mode`. Nevertheless I try to help: [According to the doc](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package#binding-within-local-keymaps) you have too many parentheses in your `:bind` command. Remove the outer parentheses. Furthermore `anaconda-mode-map` is globally defined in [anaconda-mode.el](https://github.com/proofit404/anaconda-mode/blob/master/anaconda-mode.el). So you do not really need `:map anaconda-mode-.map`.